# Why won't emojis render when rotated to 45 (or 315) degrees?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, sass, emoji

I'm having a strange problem where rendering an emoji rotated to certain angles results in the emoji failing to appear.

This seems consistent across browsers, so I'm struggling to pinpoint the issue or a reasonable solution.

**The code:**

```
<style type="text/css">
  .container {
    background-color: #55d;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 500px;
  }
  .text {
    color: #fff;
    font-size:2em;
    margin: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text">This is some text </div>
</div>
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORgQjb for a working example, note that changing the rotation, even to 44.5 degrees will bring the emoji back.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to why this occurs, or any workarounds?

**Update**
Thanks to Paulie_D and some digging, it seems this issue only manifests itself on OSX (all browsers), and not Windows (tried IE/Firefox/Chrome).

Comment: Unable to replicate in Chrome Version 54.0.2840.34 beta-m (64-bit) / FF49.0.1 / IE11 on Win10

Comment: I should clarify, have tested this in Chrome, Firefox and Safari on a mac, interesting that the problem doesn't appear in Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Emoji do seem to be an issue on iOS - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747201/removing-colours-from-html-entities-in-chrome-with-css

Comment: Works fine on Firefox and Chrome on Linux too.

Comment: Still an issue for me on OSX 10.11, Chrome 58. This seems to be the only place mentioning the issue...

Comment: Facing the same issue on Chrome Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit) macOS 10.13.1, on any angle which is a multiple of 45 degrees.

Comment: Still an issue in 2019, wouhou! Safari 12.x, Chrome 76.

Answer (score 3):

I sure don't know *why* it happens, but after some tinkering, I do have a couple of fixes to share.

#### Webkit

If a Webkit-only fix is sufficient (e.g., if you're building an Electron app), you only need to add the CSS transform `perspective(0)`, which has no visible effect, other than causing emoji to actually render.

So:

```
transform: rotate(45deg) perspective(0);
```

instead of:

```
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

Here's a fork of your example demonstrating that fix:

https://codepen.io/troywarr/pen/yEgEdr

and a reduced test case including a reference emoji to illustrate that `perspective(0)` doesn't change the emoji's appearance:

https://codepen.io/troywarr/pen/aKpKmx

#### Cross-browser

If you need a cross-browser fix, you can use a CSS animation that rotates starting at 45 degrees (or whichever multiple of 45 degrees that you need to fix) but is eternally paused:

```
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}

.working-rotated-thing {
  animation: spin 1ms; /* animation-duration must be > 0 */
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Here's a fork of your example demonstrating that fix (note that I enabled Autoprefixer to avoid messing with vendor prefixes):

https://codepen.io/troywarr/pen/mKRKZB

and a reduced test case:

https://codepen.io/troywarr/pen/oyByMx

This seems to work across browsers; I checked the latest Chrome, Firefox, and Safari in macOS High Sierra, and all were well.

Comment: Adding perspective(0) as suggested by Bungle worked for me. I experienced this issue in Chrome 78.0.3904.87 and Safari 12.1 12607.1.40.1.5 on macOS (Firefox worked properly). It occurred when rotating an image with a transition animation at the beginning and end of the rotation, but ONLY when the top-level application container's scale() transform was 1.38 or greater, and ONLY when the rotation was under 10 degrees or over 170 degrees. Fun times. Thank you @Bungle for the magic trick, and thank you Paul Grand for asking the question in the first place.

Comment: Faced similar issue in safari and chrome in mac os,  my scenario was little different though. i had the emoji text inside a free to rotate container. adding `transform:scale3d(1,1,1) perspective(10px);` worked. weirdly, it didn't work with `perspective(0)`.The container had no other transform other than rotate. But yes, your answer helped a lot. Thanks